# Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are positive integers such that $ab$ divides $a + b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are positive integers such that $ab$ divides $a + b$.

Prove that $a = b$, then prove that $a$ is either $1$ or $2$.

I was thinking using the theorem:

> If $n|a$ and $n|b$,then $n|(ax+by)$ for any $x,y\in \mathbb Z$.

Then I can derive that $ab$ divides $a$ and $b$. I could not go further. However, this doesn't seem like can help me solve the question I had.

Comment: If you can provide some context for the question, ideally including your own thoughts on it, then you'll avoid having your question voted down and possibly closed. This site isn't very friendly towards plain questions without effort being shown on the part of the asker.

Comment: I was thinking using the theorem If n|a and n|b,then n|(ax+by) for any x,y∈Z.Then I can derive that ab divides a and divides b. I could not go further. However, this doesn't seem like can help me solve the question I had.

Comment: I think I could go if a divides b and b divides a then a equals b.

Comment: @Xiang Simple things first... The product of two positive integers is *usually* larger than their sum. When is it *not* so?

Comment: that's right, therefore a is either 1 or 2. but how can you prove this?

Comment: @Xiang $\;(a-1)(b-1) \ge 0\,$ which is the same as $\,ab \ge a+b-1\,$.

Comment: Just do it: $ab|a+b$ means $a+b=k*ab$ so $k*a=\frac ab + 1$ and $\frac ab$ is an integer so $b|a$.  And $k*b = 1 + \frac ba$ so $\frac ba$ is an integer so $a|b$.  So $a=b$. $2a = k*a^2$ so $k*a = 2$ so $a|2$.  So $a=1$ or $a =2$.  Just *DO* it.

Answer (score 1):

$a$ divides $b \iff \exists k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $b=ka$.

Now, $ab$ divides $a+b\iff \exists K\in\mathbb{Z}$ s.t $a+b=Kab$.

If $a=b\Rightarrow a+a=Kaa\Rightarrow 2a=Ka^2$, remember that $a\neq0$. Then

$2=Ka$ where you have two ways.

What integer values should $K$ take to satisfy the equation?

Answer (score 1):

We have 
$$ab \mid a+b \implies ab \mid b( a+b) \implies  ab \mid b( a+b) - ab \implies  ab \mid b^2 \implies  a \mid b$$
In a similar way we can show 
$$b \mid a$$ and so 
$$a=b$$

If we substitute  $b$ by $a$ in $ab \mid a+b $ we get

$$a^2 \mid 2a \implies a \mid 2 \implies a \in \{1,2\}.$$ Both $(a,b)\in\{(1,1), (2,2)\}$ are solutons.

Answer (score 1):

$abx=(a+b)$, where $x$ is greater than or equal to $1$ ($x$ cannot be $0$)

$$x = \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}$$

This implies that $x$ must be $1$ or $2$. 
($2$ is the greatest value possible for sum of two reciprocals of natural numbers)

so if $x=1$, then $\frac{1}{a}$ and $\frac{1}{b}$ must both be $\frac{1}{2}$ and $a=b=2$.
so if $x=2$ then $\frac{1}{a}$ and $\frac{1}{b}$ must both be $1$ and $a=b=1$